# Add submenu items from an MS Access DB file to a menustrip programmatically

Tags: vb.net

I want to load programmatically some stored titles from an **MS Access DB file** and add them to a `MenuStrip` as subitems to existing submenus.

I am using this way to load my DB file, I just don't know how to add those titles into my `Menustrip` control as subitems...

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb

Public Class MainForm
    Public Provider As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source ="
    Public DataFile As String = "database.accdb"
    Public ConnString As String = Provider & DataFile
    Public MyConnection As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection
    Public DataReader As OleDbDataReader

    Public Sub ApplicationsMenu_Load()
        MyConnection.ConnectionString = ConnString
        MyConnection.Open()

        Dim str As String = "SELECT * FROM ApplicationsPaths"

        Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(str, MyConnection)
        DataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader

        Try
            While DataReader.Read()
                'Add submenu items code here!!!
            End While
            MyConnection.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```

Into an other project I used this way below to add some `labels` into a `FlowLayoutPanel` control. I want to do something similar... I just missing the syntax!!!

```
While DataReader.Read()
            Dim lbl As New Label()
            Dim count As Integer = StandardPaths_HiddenFlowLayoutPanel.Controls.OfType(Of Label)().ToList().Count
            lbl.Name = "Path_" & DataReader("TagNum").ToString
            lbl.Tag = DataReader("TagNum").ToString
            lbl.Text = DataReader("Path").ToString
            lbl.AutoEllipsis = True
            lbl.AutoSize = True
            lbl.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleRight
            StandardPaths_HiddenFlowLayoutPanel.Controls.Add(lbl)
        End While
```

**EDIT:**

I found this way below to add titles from DB file to `MenuStrip` but it loads them as top menus.

```
While DataReader.Read()
            Dim SubItems As New ToolStripMenuItem
            SubItems.Text = DataReader("AppName").ToString
            MainForm_MenuStrip.Items.Add(SubItems)
        End While
```

How can I add them as items to an existing submenu? I am trying `MainForm_MenuStrip.DropDownItems.Add(SubItems)` and I get `'DropDownItems' is not a member of 'MenuStrip'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I found it!!! First I had to put the name of the submenu where I want to add those items and not the name of `MenuStrip` control. And then, I had to put `DropDownItems.Add` and not `Items.Add` probably because I want to add titles into a drop down item.

```
While DataReader.Read()
        Dim SubItems As New ToolStripMenuItem
        SubItems.Text = DataReader("AppName").ToString
        ApplicationsActions_MenuItem.DropDownItems.Add(SubItems)
    End While
```

Answer (score 0):

Load the text/menuitems/whatever that is in the database file into a textbox,listbox or simillar control.Make it invisible.Then on form load, use this :

```
 For each item in listbox1.items
 'this is untested
 'for example, if your menustrip's item name is FILE then
 FileToolStripMenuItem.items.add(item)
 NEXT
```

that's all

Comment: Your example does the same work as `MainForm_MenuStrip.Items.Add(SubItems)` which I show on my example. The question is, how to add those data into an existing sub menu and not at the top!!!

Comment: Having an invisible `ListBox` merely for storing data in is a bad solution. Use a [**`List(Of T)`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx) instead.

Comment: i would've suggested a List(of string) ..it just didn't cross my mind then

Comment: hey, @VisualVincent, can you please help me out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47678026/adding-content-text-in-rectangle-wpf)

Comment: Sometimes we forget :). Though it is good to keep in mind that you should only use UI elements (controls) if you are actually going to display data, otherwise they're just unnecessary overhead.

Comment: yeah bro...sorry again